# How can I resolve the 403 error when uploading images from Unity to my S3 bucket?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

AWS keep sending 403 error when I'm trying to connect to my S3 through Unity.

I configured all right policies and rules and everything to be able to send my images from unity to my S3 bucket. On postman everything work well, but from unity it keeps failing. I really don't know which kind of policy/permission I'm missing that I should set up to my S3 work...

All I tried was set up my S3, add rules and policies, set up my lambda correctly and my gateway to give me access to upload my json class through a link.

Even game "all access to my S3" policy rules and..... nothing.

From unity unfortunately, the only error response is 403 http forbidden error.

```
//from screenshot script
byte[] pngArray = screenshotTexture.EncodeToPNG();
string base64img = Convert.ToBase64String(pngArray);
        
        
RequestUploadModel requestModel = new RequestUploadModel
{
   pathFile = GetNameFile(),
   base64 = base64img
 };
                
 string payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestModel);
        
 print(payload);
 ApiManager.instance.UploadS3WebRequest(payload);

//from ApiManager script
private IEnumerator UploadFile(string payload)
    {
        UnityWebRequest getUrlRequest = UnityWebRequest.Put(Constants.ENDPOINT_UPLOAD,payload);
        yield return getUrlRequest.SendWebRequest();

        if (getUrlRequest.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Error getting presigned URL: {getUrlRequest.error}");
            yield break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How does unity log into aws?

Comment: In addition to the question by @jerry, I would try and checkout the logs in AWS Cloudwatch Logs. There you can see all the API calls Unity is trying to make including the error message.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah hi, I set it on public so it should post without login (if that's what you are asking).

Comment: @TrygviLaksafoss I'm new to it, so I did not set up cloudwatch and I have no idea how to do it at this moment.